# What does it mean for a subgroup $H$ of an abelian group $G$ to be less than or equal to $G$?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, notation, abelian-groups

I am reading through some linear algebra lecture notes and have come across the following notation:

$$K \leq G,$$

where $G$ is an abelian group and $K$ is a subgroup of $G$.
What does this notation mean, please?
I have checked Google, but haven't found any explanation so far.

Comment: You did not google very long ? Here is a [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols_by_subject), found by google. Search for "subgroup" in this list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That notation is meant to indicate the K is a subgroup of G. That is all it says and is just a nice shorthand.

Comment: Haha yes it means eventually you run out of ideas for symbols